# SQL sum with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I have a query that need to have a sum up value, but in one of my table's column, there's an increment and decrements value. 
For decremented value, the value of it need to be as negative even it is stored as positive value in the table. 
While for incremented value, it remains as positive.

My query look like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0' THEN -(ACTIVITY_VALUE)
        ELSE ACTIVITY_VALUE
        END
        ) AS NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
FROM V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT
WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('0','1') 
    AND EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789' 
    AND ((YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH <= 4)
        OR
        (YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR <2014)
        OR
        (YEAR = 2013 AND MONTH >= 5)) 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
```

It return this result:
NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
391.00  
 
-600.00

I need the value to be as -209 (the total of those two number)

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh thank you so much! it works! thank you!

Comment: @hotseetotsee `(YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR <2014)` - wat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently grouping the sum per unique combination of month and year. If you want the total sum, just drop the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0' THEN -(ACTIVITY_VALUE)
        ELSE ACTIVITY_VALUE
        END
        ) AS NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
FROM V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT
WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('0','1') 
    AND EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789' 
    AND ((YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH <= 4)
        OR
        (YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR <2014)
        OR
        (YEAR = 2013 AND MONTH >= 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0' THEN
            - (ACTIVITY_VALUE)
        ELSE
            ACTIVITY_VALUE
        END
    ) AS NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
FROM
    V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT
WHERE
    ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('0', '1')
AND EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789'
AND (
    (YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH <= 4)
    OR (YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR < 2014)
    OR (YEAR = 2013 AND MONTH >= 5)
)
```